# Zotero integration in Overleaf fails on accented characters

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, accents, zotero

I am using the Zotero integration in Overleaf with bibtex (not biblatex) due to the requirement of a journal.

I have been trying to compile with entries containing names with accented characters.

Unfortunately this fails with the corresponding error:

> Blockquote
> LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (�.).
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.237 ...{P.~Gueriau}, \bibinfo{author}{�.~Anheim}
> ,
> The document does not appear to be in UTF-8 encoding. Try adding \UseRawInputEncoding as
> the first line of the file or specify an encoding such as \usepackage
> [latin1]{inputenc} in the document preamble. Alternatively, save the
> file in UTF-8 using your editor or another tool

What would you advise?

Many thanks.

Comment: it is impossible to say from the information given whether the message is correct and the file is badly encoded or if it is a spurious message due to some other issue, but in general for bibtex it is best to use ascii command markup so `{\'e}` not `é`

Comment: Looks like bibtex broke a utf8 char while trying to create an initial.

Comment: Hi both, the bibtex is automatically generated from Zotero so I have no control. I can have a look if the output is correctly encoded in UTF8